# Android Studio gradle build for android compatible Android – 5.0 Lollipop etc

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I am able to successfully build APK file in Android studio by selecting minimum Android version is 5.0 (Lollipop) as part of creating android project in Android studio.

But when i try to install APK in Android mobile ( 5.0 version), it gives Package Parsing error.

i have also set minifyEnabled to true

i have noticed that Android studio includes "compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0" though i select minimum version is Lollipop (5.0) . V24.2.0 is for marshmallow.

any expert help me on this

## AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

## build.gradle

enter code here

```
   apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
  android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.simpletest"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}   
}
   dependencies {
     compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
     testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
   compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
    }
```

Comment: post full build.gradle code and AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: thanks for helping. I have updated

Answer (score 2):

I got this error while building the android application

1. I made changes into build.gradle file(change 24.2.0 to 23.0.0) or change the version number.

   ```
   defaultConfig {
   applicationId "your package name"
   minSdkVersion 14
   targetSdkVersion 23
   versionCode 1
   versionName "1.0"
   }
      buildTypes {
   release {
       minifyEnabled false
       proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),   'proguard-rules.pro'
   }
   }
    dexOptions {
    preDexLibraries = false
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
   }
   packagingOptions {
   exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
   exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }
     android {
     lintOptions {
       checkReleaseBuilds false
     }
    }
    defaultConfig {
     multiDexEnabled true
    }
    }
     dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.0'
        }
   ```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29682002/error-on-installing-apk-parsing-the-package

Comment: or its version issue. My target was 6.0. mean while my phone was 5.0.0. I changed the target version in my project and its works fine. Thanks

Comment: any idea why android studio adds com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0 automatically when selecting minversion is 5.0

Comment: Yes because of latest update https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html

Comment: 23.0.0 for Marshmallow not for Lollipop

Comment: Then add a Lollipop version :)

Comment: Marshmallow I have added for target version.

Comment: will do. I am confused with this .in build.gradle we add minSdkVersion 14
targetSdkVersion 23. but dependency compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0' for target version only what about for 5.0 , should we are dependency for both 14 and 23. or 23.0.0. is backward compatible

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26694108/what-is-the-difference-between-compilesdkversion-and-targetsdkversion

Comment: Google detailed article - https://medium.com/google-developers/picking-your-compilesdkversion-minsdkversion-targetsdkversion-a098a0341ebd#.mr0vup70u

Comment: Hi Nancy i modified my build.gradle config and generated APK and tested on Lollipop android mobile and am still getting package parse error.but i tested on kitkat v4.1 mobile and it is working. any idea why it is not working in lollipop version i looked at the setting and i have selected option to allow unkown source any other setting

Comment: Delete all the previous version or all cache then reinstall apk or Check the permission.

Answer (score 0):

use the following code below the buildTypes  in build.Gradle file

```
    packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt' // will not include NOTICE file
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt' // will not include LICENSE file
}
```

hope this will help you .
Happy Coding....