# Android Studio - Error Installing APK

Tags: android, apk

I am a new user to Android Studio. I took a class over the summer and all my projects worked (and still work). I have followed all the advice from all the advice columns but I am still getting  "Session 'app': Error Installing APK" when I try running my latest projects on my Samsung S4 mini. Again, all the other projects from this summer still work. I have tried

- restarting everything (android studio, computer, phone, etc)
- I have reloaded Android Studio
- I have created multiple signatures and followed the directions on https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html

Does anyone have any other suggestions??

Comment: check if your device is visible in `adb devices`

Comment: Try to free some memory of phone and make sure device is connected properly.

Comment: In response to all the comments/answers: M.S.P - yes the device is visible in adb.  14bce109 - I have 11GB of free memory and the device is connected properly. I just deleted all the old apps and tried them again and they worked. Duke79 - Yes, I have looked at all those articles and tried all the applicable ones. Still no help.

Comment: Figured it out!!!!  Do not put apostrophes in the file name!! I was calling it TheTrucker'sTracker and it read the apostrophe as &pos or something like that. Moral of the story - do not use punctuation in file names.

Answer (score 1):

(can't comment yet, so the answer)

Have you seen these -

[Session 'app': Error Installing APK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37015030/session-app-error-installing-apk)

[Session 'app' error while installing APK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38450717/session-app-error-while-installing-apk)

[Error on installing apk - parsing the package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29682002/error-on-installing-apk-parsing-the-package)

[Android error: Failed to install *.apk on device *: timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775603/android-error-failed-to-install-apk-on-device-timeout)

Comment: Switching from a USB 3.0 port to a USB 2.0 port solved for me. It's one of the answers to the first question.

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this error uncheck the instant run in **File >Settings >Build,Execution,Deployment > Instant Run**

This works 100%.

Answer (score 0):

Enable "Install Via USB" feature form developer setting of your android phone.

1. Go to Additional setting -> Developer setting (Provided you have enabled it by clicking on version for multiple tymes )
2. Enable "Install Via USB"

Good luck