# Android - Error on installing apk - parsing the package

Tags: android, apk

I have a very similar issue, to this one:
[Error on installing apk - parsing the package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29682002/error-on-installing-apk-parsing-the-package)

but the answers there didn't help me.

Shortly, I have an application that I develop, and in each big change that i make, I check it in my phone also. And it never had problems until now.
I didn't do it for a week, and I changed things in the code, that I don't realy remember (problems with Git, another issue...).
The app is using Firebase, so I had to update SDK on Android studio to 2.2.3.
Maybe this is the problem? And if so, what is the solution? I can't think on another reason.
On emulator it works great. Only on device it's not working.
Until now, i just entered into APK folder in the project, and sent "app-debug.apk" to my mail, and I opened it in my phone mailbox.
Now this file leads to "There is a problem parsing the package.".

So I tried to get the APK in different ways:
1. build-> build APK.
2. build-> generate signed APK, as mentioned in the answer in the link.
3. take the release APK.
4. take the debug APK.
Nothing works!

I tried it on 2 devices:

```
Meizu M2, Android 5.1

LG 3 beat.
```

build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
}



}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

AndroidManifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="some package....">


<!--
            android:label="@string/app_name"

    -->

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"

    android:label="Mission List"

    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
                    some info...
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".newList">
                    some info...
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".viewGroups">
                   some info...
    </activity>


    <activity android:name=".tasks">
                    some info...
    </activity>
</application>
```

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will happens when your are installing the app with applicationID which is already available on device.Two app with same appId.

Comment: Thanks @Patel Jaimin, i tried to change the application id with this guide: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_pneBqkFqfw but it says: "Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> No matching client found for package name 'the new name that i gave"

Comment: anyway, i tried on third clean device, and it works there! thanks a lot!

Comment: You need to change package name and according to appId in your bulid.gradle file.